# access denied for inserting item in sharepoint list by ECMA script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Unable to insert item in sharepoint list by ECMA script with visitor privilege.
I have added `<sharepoint:FormDigest>` control in master page of my site.
I am able to run the code successfully by system account.
[image]
Here is my code :

```
try {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        id = "123";
        var nameOnly = "ABC";
        var lstFavouritePosts = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DEF');
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.newListItem = lstFavouritePosts.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        newListItem.set_item('Title', id);
        newListItem.set_item('User', nameOnly); 
        newListItem.update();
        context.load(newListItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        return false;
    }
catch(msg)
        {
            alert(msg);
        }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert('ABC');
        return false;
    }
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    return false;
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to give the context user information. This could be why the request is denied.

Try changing the code within your try block to:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = context.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser); 
id = "123";
var nameOnly = "ABC";
var lstFavouritePosts = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DEF');
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.newListItem = lstFavouritePosts.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
newListItem.set_item('Title', id);
newListItem.set_item('User', nameOnly); 
newListItem.update();
context.load(newListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
return false;
```

Comment: Sorry I've just seen that you want to add the Item as a visitor, so my suggestion wouldn't work. Does your list allow this? I would imagine you need to set permissions to allow guests to add items to it

Comment: Thank you.can u give hint to do that ?

Comment: It works but i dont want to give permission b'coz list is visible to visitor and i dont want to allow them to insert items in list manually.I only want to allow them to insert through UI.And code is for 'Mark as Favourite'.So i have to insert their ID,Name in list.so...

Comment: Ok, well at least we know why you are getting the access denied message. Can't you just hide the List from the navigation menu so that they can't access it, and therefore add a new item through the Sharepoint UI? An alternative to this is creating a specific account which your code uses to insert the item on behalf of the user. You can hide the sharepoint columns Added by and create a new one and set the value for it programmatically.

Comment: can u give a li'll hint how to do that or a link as an example for doing it by another account ?